# Is gzip compression available for GitHub pages?

Tags: performance, page-speed, gzip, github

I'm using GitHub pages to host my site. While checking Google PageSpeed Insights, it recommends that I enable gzip compression. Since I have a static site hosted on GitHub, I'm not sure that is possible.

Is it possible to enable gzip compression on GitHub?

Answer (score 15):

As covered [here](http://code.lancepollard.com/github-as-a-cdn/), [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/) is served with [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) and automatically [gzip's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) content.

You can confirm gzip compression for your site by checking the HTTP headers with online tools like [this](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) one. Enter the URL to a webpage or resource, and type in `gzip` under "Accept-Encoding" to indicate that the HTTP client (i.e., the online testing tool in this case) accepts gzip compression, as most browsers do.

You might review the other information and suggestions [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules) to optimize serving as well.

Answer (score 4):

besides Dan's answer, depending on your static-site generators, there can be some plugins that make the compressed `.gz`-ed version offline while generating the site. By that way, your server can serve those `gz`-ed pages directly.

For example, `Pelican` users can use [gzip_cache](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/gzip_cache).
For Jekyll, there's [jekyll-press](http://www.jekyll-plugins.com/plugins/jekyll-press),